# Android Socket.io emits twice instead of once?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I'm using android socket.io but the problem is that emit event runs twice instead of once , i mean that i wrote just one emit code in the onCreate method , but it sends two request for the server ?
I searched alot but not found anything .

I use node js in the backend ,and my code has not any problems .

Is there a bug in socket.io for android ?

Here is my code :

```
    SocketManager.getInstance().connect();
    // Creating Bids
    final Handler mHandler04 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mHandler04.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().emit("allc", "some");
            SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().on("allcRes", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    g.context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) args[0];
                            arrayComps.clear();
                            Log.d(TAG, "run: " + jsonArray);
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    createView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("realprice"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("starttime"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("img"));
                                    CustomViewCompetition css  = (CustomViewCompetition) LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildAt(i);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    final Handler bidsupdateHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    bidsupdateHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().on("bidsupdate", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    final JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) args[0];
                    g.context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "run in bidsupdate");
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    bidsMap.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("key"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("value"));
                                }

                                for (int i = 0; i < LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                    CustomViewCompetition cs = (CustomViewCompetition) LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildAt(i);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "run in cs " + cs.txtCsRealPrice.getText());

                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

the Problem is when i get the cs.txtCsTitle.getText() it is just showing me one of them

Comment: Where are you writing this code? I mean in onCreate method or onResume etc ?

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan I'm writing these codes inside of onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().emit("allc", "some");
```

just after:

```
SocketManager.getInstance().connect();
```

So your code will be like

```
SocketManager.getInstance().connect();
SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().emit("allc", "some");
```

And remove from where you are already using in handler. Also you dont need handlers why you are using handlers? Create your listener and emit your subscription out of handlers it needs to be created or subscribed once. On creation of emitter listener pass views if you need to update any view. then update the views here you may need runnable to update UI on uiThread.

Create Class as follows:

```
public class YourListener implements Emitter.Listener
{
private yourView view;

public YourListener (View view)
{
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public void call(Object... args)
{
    // do your work here
}
}
```

and replace below code :

```
SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().on("allcRes", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                g.context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) args[0];
                        arrayComps.clear();
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: " + jsonArray);
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                createView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("realprice"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("starttime"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("img"));
                                CustomViewCompetition css  = (CustomViewCompetition) LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildAt(i);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

with:

```
SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().on("your_subscription", new YourListener (yourView));
```